# Run local file that imports matplotlib in colab

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-colaboratory

Until now, I can only make matplotlib in colab work by adding the magic word: %matplotlib inline.
But the issue is that I want to sometimes run a local file, by doing for example: !python main.py.
But if main.py uses matplotlib, the code will not work properly, because the magic word is not present.
Anyways the question is: how can I run a local file that uses matplotlib.

If just try to run:

```
%matplotlib inline

!python main.py
```

I am pretty sure it will not work.

Comment: Welcome to SO; "*I am pretty sure it won't work*" is not enough for a valid SO question. Please run it and report any *specific* error you may get. Plus, question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

You can try %run

```
%run main.py
```

It should be able to show plots.